# PHP Convert array element to string prints "Array"

Tags: php

I query a database to obtain an array of results.

```
$usersArray = $db->getAllUsers();  // db-Query
```

If I print out the array's var_dump, its content is structured in form of other arrays:

```
array(9) { [0]=> **array**(1) { ["column"]=> string(20) "..." } [1]=> **array**(1) { ["column"] (remaining 8 are the same).
```

Now I need these values (which are correct, so far) to be casted as strings, so that:

```
array(9) { [0]=> **string**(1) { ["column"]=> string(20) "..." } [1]=> **string**(1) { ["column"] ....
```

There are several answers to this here and elsewhere, such as

-array_map: here I can actually cast the content as string, but- it prints "Array" instead the value. It tried then getting the content via

```
$users = array_map('strval',implode( $usersArray));
$users = array_map('strval', print_r($usersArray));
```

Neither of those worked.

Is there a method through which I could cast the content as string **and** get the content ? Or should I rewrite the query to format the result as strings ?

Comment: Are you trying to cast array to string? `serialize($usersArray);`

Comment: Why can't you just get the values like this? $usersArray[0]['column'] ? Why are you trying to cast as string?

Comment: And what do you mean print_r() and implode() doesn't work? Show us how you've tried using these functions.

Comment: $users = implode($usersArray); (didn't work). $users = print_r($usersArray); didn't work either..

Comment: @Romana edit your question please don't add code in the comments.

Comment: @Romana You using them both wrong. Implode requires two parameters. And you can't assign print_r to a variable.

Comment: @Daan You can assign print_r() to a variable by passing TRUE as second parameter

Comment: @Romana can you show your full array, and what you want to achieve.

Comment: @Samosa You're right I always use var_dump mixed them up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a wrong understanding of types or at least this:

```
array(9) { [0]=> **string**(1) { ["column"]=> string(20) "..." } [1]=> **string**(1) { ["column"] ....
```

doesn't make any sense. You believe you want elements to be of type string but yet contain array data which really doesn't work.
What you actually want is a different array structure but you are heading in the wrong direction for that.

You basically have two options:

1. Modify the getAllUsers() method in a way that returns your data in a structure you actually need.
2. Modify the data after you have received it. Obviously there's no builtin function convert_data_to_how_i_want_them() - so a basic understanding of arrays is required.
   Basically you create a new array and copy those values you need to the position you need them at.

Something like this should do the trick in this case:

```
$out = array();
foreach($in as => $value) {
    $out[] = $value['column'];
}
```

Comment: Good explanation- you also pointed correctly out the options. I implemented the second version. Thanks!